# How to get the price of an item on Amazon?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make a list of items and there prices. I am getting these items from Amazon. I searched this on Google and I only found how to get prices with Node.js. How can I get the price of these items with JavaScript?

```js
let itemPrice;

function getPrice(url) {
    let price;
    price = // gets the item's price
    return price;
}

window.onload = function () {
    itemPrice = getPrice(url);
}
```

Comment: `// gets the item's price` part is the call to amazon service?

Comment: @Derek.W Yes, it is.

Comment: So this will be the ajax part?

Comment: @Derek.W Yes it will be.

Answer (score 1):

On `getPrice` function, it is needed to get the item price from the url using `ajax` request so it will be `async` func part.

Therfore, it will be good to make `getPrice` function to return `Promise` to process asynchronously.

```js
let itemPrice;

function getPrice(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let price;
    price = 35; // gets the item's price
    return resolve(price);
  });
}

window.onload = function () {
  getPrice("testurl")
    .then((price) => {
      itemPrice = price;
      console.log('Item Price', itemPrice);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handling error
    });
}
```